# Adding resources to be deployed in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, matlab, deployment, setup-deployment

I have made a simple program in MATLAB and used the dotnetbuilder to generate a DLL file to be used in VB.NET. I'm new to VB.NET so I don't know much about it.

I have the following files from matlab after building the .NET package:

- MCRInstaller.exe
- DiseaseComp.dll
- DiseaseComp.prj

These files where used in my VB program to do certain functions. Here's my VB code:

```
Imports MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays
Imports MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility
Imports DiseaseComp


Public Class Form1
    Dim fileloc As String
    Dim dataloc As String = "C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\Program\Disease\Data\PreTrainedDisease.mat"
    Dim result As MWArray
    Dim detect As New DiseaseLABClass


    Private Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
        If ofdUpload.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            picboxImage.Image = Image.FromFile(ofdUpload.FileName)
            fileloc = ofdUpload.FileName
            txtLocation.Text = fileloc
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcess.Click

        result = detect.DiseaseLAB(fileloc, dataloc).ToString

        If result.ToString = "1" Then
            txtDisease.Text = "Bacterial Leaf Blight"
        ElseIf result.ToString = "2" Then
            txtDisease.Text = "Brown Spot"
        ElseIf result.ToString = "3" Then
            txtDisease.Text = "Rice Blast"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I want to happen is to make an installer of the project that I made in VB. Right now I have the InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition. Here are my concerns regarding the deployment of this project:

1. I want to make an installer of this project so that the program will be installed in **C:\Program Files\Disease Detection** or **C:\Program Files (x86)\Disease Detection**
2. I have this in my code `Dim dataloc As String = "C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\Program\Disease\Data\PreTrainedDisease.mat"`. As you can see the file location is fixed.  What I want is for **PreTrainedDisease.mat** to be installed in **C:\Program Files\Disease Detection\Dataset**. Then the value of the **dataloc** will automatically equivalent to where the **PreTrainedDisease.mat** is located after the installation.
3. I also want the **MCRInstaller.exe** and the **.NET Framework 4.5 or 4.5.1** to be installed whenever the installer detects that the computer doesn't have the Matlab Runtime Compiler and the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is more related to InstallShield...

1) You need to create a form during the installation, asking the user to input the installation folder.

2) You can configure a [Windows Environment Path][1] variable to store the location where your application was installed. This variable must be set during instalation. So, the location of PreTrainedDisease.mat would be /Dataset.

3) I´m pretty sure InstallShield must have a way to check if a software is installed or not. I have worked with Visual Studio Setup project and it was quite easy. Check if there are any pre requisites property.

Comment: can you send me a link for the tutorial on how to do this? Also, is the free version of the installshield enough to do the job?